# How to have all contents of a directory run as if they were in your CWD?

Tags: shell, zsh, macos

Say I have a few directories:

```
/Users/user1/ApplicationThing/
/Users/user1/Documents/
/Users/user1/other/directory/it/doesnt/matter/
```

Say there was a file `main.sh` in `.../ApplicationThing/`, which also depends on another file `dependancy.sh`.

I want to be able to be in any other directory, and be able to run `main.sh`, with it's WD as my CWD, as if the contents `.../ApplicationThing/` directory was in every other directory on the system. Not as in with `$PATH`, but as if the contents were actually inside of the directory, but shouldn't pop up in autocompletions or even `ls -l`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the ApplicationThing should be fixed to find its dependencies from a specific location, even when called with a different working directory.

You could do it by setting an environment variable:

```
export ApplicationThingHome=/Users/user1/ApplicantionThing
```

and referring to all dependencies of the `main.sh` using the value of that variable (with optionally a nice default if the variable is unset), e.g.

```
${ApplicationThingHome:-/usr/local/ApplicationThingDefaultDir}/dependancy.sh
```

instead of

```
./dependancy.sh
```

Then you could put `main.sh`'s directory into `$PATH` and use it from any directory.

Your proposed solution would have a problem: if you are in any other directory and wish to create a file named, say, `main.sh` or `dependency.sh` there, you would end up overwriting ApplicationThing's respective files instead. You would literally be unable to have/use any other `main.sh` but the one that belongs to ApplicationThing... and directories were invented precisely to avoid problems like that!

Of course, you could make it a condition that the "pseudo-files" would be there only when `main.sh` is executed first... but then you would need another set of tools to see what `main.sh` sees in order to troubleshoot it whenever it does not do what you expect.

If you can't fix ApplicationThing, you could make a wrapper script to call ApplicationThing from anywhere on the system, and place *that* script in a directory that is included in your $PATH:

```
#!/bin/sh
# set the correct working directory for silly ApplicationThing
cd /Users/user1/ApplicationThing
# if ApplicationThing has any other environment requirements, 
# this would be a great place to ensure they're satisfied too.

# Now execute the main.sh of ApplicationThing, giving it any 
# command line arguments that were given to this script, exactly as-is.
exec ./main.sh "$@"
```

Since this script will be executed as a separate process, the `cd` command in the script will not affect the session calling the script at all. The `exec` keyword in running the `main.sh` avoids leaving an extra process in between the calling shell and the `main.sh`.

With this approach, if `main.sh` takes filenames as parameters, you would have to supply them as absolute pathnames, since any relative pathnames would be interpreted by `main.sh` as relative to ApplicationThing's directory, not as relative to CWD of the calling session.

If that is a problem, you might write a more elaborate pre-processing for the command line parameters before passing them to `main.sh`. [This StackExchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572030/bash-script-absolute-path-with-os-x) has some ideas you might find applicable.